# template_name in LogoutView not working on django2.1 python3.7

Tags: django-templates, python-3.7, django-2.1

Below is default setting in django.contrib.auth.views.LogoutViews,

```
template_name = 'registration/logged_out.html'
```

i configurate my app's urls.py like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

app_name = 'account'
urlpatterns = [
    #path("login/", views.user_login, name="user_login"),
    path("login/", LoginView.as_view(), name="user_login"),
    path("nlogin/", LoginView.as_view(), {"template_name":"account/login.html"}),
    path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="user_logout"),
    path("logoutt/", LogoutView.as_view(), {"template_name":"account/logout.html"}),
]
```

"template_name":"account/login.html" works properly, but "template_name":"account/logout.html" seems make no difference, what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You need to pass it as a parameter of the `as_view`.

Comment: Furthermore I have the idea that the custom `template_name` for the `LoginView` will not work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the *class-based* variant, you pass settings to the view through the `.as_view` (the so called [`**initkwargs`](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.contrib.auth.views/LoginView/#as_view)) method:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView

app_name = 'account'

urlpatterns = [
    #path("login/", views.user_login, name="user_login"),
    path("login/", LoginView.as_view(), name="user_login"),
    path("nlogin/", LoginView.as_view(template_name='account/login.html')),
    path("logout/", LogoutView.as_view(), name="user_logout"),
    path("logoutt/", LogoutView.as_view(template_name='account/logout.html')),
]
```

Otherwise the parameters will end up in the `self.kwargs`, and the class-based view does not inspect these.

The [documentation on the **`LoginView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView) mentions this as well as a list of parameters you can pass as `**initkwargs`.

Comment: ok, thank you a lot, i read a book in django 1.0, template_name pass in the style of url(r"^login/$", auth_views.login, {"template_name":"account/loing.html"}), but i act on django 2.1, pass settings in path, i confused by this two way, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

According to [Willem Van Onsem's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52161589/10195623), i found the key problem is i mixed up two way of urlpatterns, like this:

1. url（） and regular expression type in urls.py (I learned in django 1.10.1 tutorial）

   ```
   from django.conf.urls import url
   from django.contrib.auth import views
   urlpatterns = [
       url(r"^login/$", views.login, {"template_name"="account/login.html"}, name='user_login'),
   ]
   ```
2. path() type in urls.py(django 2.1 docs)

   ```
   from django.urls import path
   from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
   urlpatterns = [
       path("login/", LoginView.as_view(template_name="account/login.html"),name="user_login"),
   ]
   ```

It's obvious that there be two major difference to note:

1. url import from django.conf.urls, but path import from django.urls straightly, and path type is new in django 2.0, **path seems more simple**
2. in django 2.1, LoginView & LogoutView settings pass on as_view(), compare to older expression *views.login, {"template_name"="account/login.html"}*, **simpler too**